# Streaming Android screen to YouTube, Twitch etc

Tags: screen, streaming, screencast

I have Lenovo Yoga Book, which I would like to use for drawing - it has a drawing tablet with a stylus.

I would like to use it to draw on Slack meetings. However, screen sharing does not work on Android version of Slack. So I was thinking I could stream the screen to YouTube and send my colleagues a link.

- I have tried Mobizen, but that gives me "Stream Error: 901".
- I have tried Twitch app but that's only for viewing.

Does anyone have some working solution?

Android 7.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

I figured out. The [Omlet Arcade](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobisocial.arcade&hl=en&gl=US)
app works like a charm.

It even supports internal audio streaming, but only from Android 10 which supports it itself.

---

In case anyone has the same use case as me - drawing - then the app I use for collaborative drawing is Aggie.io, and for stylus-on-tablet drawing I use Lenovo NoteSaver, which one of the few apps which supports the drawing pad.